# Asp.Net Core AddAutoMapper Dynamic from Multi Projects

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I want to register AutoMapper form different project each project have it's public function to register his functions
like this

```
public static class Binder
{
    public static IServiceCollection UseInjection(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MappingProfile));
    }
}
```

if i do it on each layer it's not working .
i need to write everything ones
like this : (work)

```
  services.AddAutoMapper(
            typeof(Project1.Mapping.MappingProfile),
            typeof(Project2.Mapping.MappingProfile),
            typeof(Project3.Mapping.MappingProfile));
```

i try to scan the folder for the dll's and take the type to register ones :

```
var target = typeof(JustForLocation).Assembly;
       
        bool DefaultFilter(Assembly x) => true;

        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(target.Location) ?? throw new Exception();

        var assembliesToLoad = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll").
            Select(dll => Assembly.LoadFile(dll))
            .Where(DefaultFilter)
            .ToList();

        assembliesToLoad.Add(target);

        var types = assembliesToLoad.SelectMany(a => a.GetExportedTypes()).Where(w => w.BaseType == typeof(AutoMapper.Profile)).ToArray();
        services.AddAutoMapper(types);
```

but it's still throw error from the AutoMappe that say:

> AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Mapping types

any advise why it's happen ?

Comment: do you want to configure mapper ?

Comment: I want to register the mapping profile

Comment: dapper........?

Comment: i want it to be dynamic load so if i send dll to othe team it will register it self

Answer (score 1):

```
 // Auto mapper registration 
 services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup).Assembly, typeof(BaseRepository).Assembly);

 // Dapper Column Mapping
 SqlMapper.SetTypeMap(typeof(Sample), new ColumnTypeMapper(typeof(Sample)));
```

Comment: hi thank you for the answer but this way is the easy way i want to to do dynamic 
so i tomorrow i add more layer the auto mapper will register automatically

Comment: it will auto register for all layer except if you need some customization...column mapping was added just for if you want to map different column name to different name...